# App crashing when on nexus7 but works on emulator android

Tags: android, nexus-7

I have created a main screen to have 3 buttons. And one of them is to open another page that displays data from my database in a textview. It works perfectly on the emulator on my laptop but when I copy the files to my Nexus 7 that button crashes the application. All other buttons work fine.

here's the code, very basic:

```
viewFlare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bViewFlare);

viewFlare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent openViewFlare = new Intent("com.example.project.SQLFLAREVIEW");
                startActivity(openViewFlare);
            }
        });
```

it calls this page:

```
public class SQLFlareView extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlflareview);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLFlareinfo);

        Calms info = new Calms(this);
        info.open();
        //System.out.print("THIS IS THIS OPEN");
        String data = info.getFlareData();
        //System.out.print("ABOUT TO CLOSE");
        info.close();
        textView.setText(data);

    }
}
```

If anyone would have any ideas I would be very appreciative, I have banged my head about this problem for a while.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash.

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace ? You can get it form logcat

Comment: sorry guys this is the first time I have tried to use this device, as I'm sure you have guessed :/ how would I be able to get the logcat from the device? I can get logcat from the emulator through adb in the terminal on my laptop

Comment: sorry I have found how to debug the device.. The logs are this

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime( 7885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity C
mponentInfo{com.example/com.example.SQLFlareView}: java.lang.NullPointerExcepti
n
E/AndroidRuntime( 7885):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActi
ity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7885):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActiv
ty(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7885):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(Activi
yThread.java:141)

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?  Invocation problems can usually be traced back to a bad entry in the manifest.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.project.MYACTIVITY"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SQLFlareView">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.project.SQLFLAREVIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          </intent-filter> </activity>

Comment: Sorry again guys, the problem has been fixed, the R file had been messed around with. I cleaned the code in the device and used a new fresh build and everything works fine again. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Intent openViewFlare = new Intent("com.example.project.SQLFLAREVIEW");
```

To this:

```
Intent openViewFlare = new Intent(name_of_current_class.this, SQLFLAREVIEW.class");
```